# What will be the output of the program?

Tags: c

```
main( )
{
int i = -2;
 +i;
printf(“i = %d, +i = %d\n”, i, +i);
}
```

I thought "+i" statement would return error but i was wrong ,so i'm confused now. Please can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Were you able to compile and run the program? What was your output?

Comment: i=-2, +i=-2; this was the output.

Comment: @SourabhDuklan so why are you surprised by this output? What output did you expect?

Comment: @SourabhDuklan Please refer to an up-to-date list of C operators.  C has many binary (two-operand) operators, and a few unary (one-operand) operators.  A few, like `-`, can be used with either one or two operands.  And `-` is not the only operator in this category.

Comment: For the line `+i;`, a good compiler will warn with something like "`warning: statement has no effect`".  If instead of `+i;`, the line were `i+1;`, would you expect that to return an error?

Answer (score 2):

I believe `+` in this case is being treated as a unary operator that means "positive" (just like the `-` in `int i = -2;` means "negative"), so `+i` and `i` have the same value.

Comment: You should not use _I believe_ in an answer. Either you know, or you don't.

Answer (score 1):

In C, a fundamental type of statement is an *expression statement*. It has the basic form of `expression;`.

We use expression statements to do things such as by assignments or function calls:

```
x = 3;
printf("%d\n", x);
```

In C, `x = 3` is an expression. At this point in your learning, you may think of it as an “action statement” of some sort, a statement that assigns a value. However, to give C flexibility, expressions were generalized, and things that were separate statements in earlier programming languages were made into expressions. An assignment expression does two things: It stores a value in the left operand, and it produces a value that can be further used. The value produced is the value stored in the left operand. So the value of `x = 3` is 3.

This means we can assign the result of an assignment to another object, as in:

```
b = (a = 3);  // Stores 3 in b.
```

or just:

```
b = a = 3;
```

We can also use the value of an assignment expression in other ways:

```
b = (a = 3) + 2; // Stores 5 in b.
printf("%d\n", (a = 3) * 2);  // Prints "6" (and a new-line).
```

The effect of storing a value is technically called a *side effect* of the assignment. Producing a value is its main effect in the C semantics, even though programmers mostly use assignments for their side effects, rather than their main effects.

`printf` sends output to the standard output stream. That is its side effect. Its main effect is to return the number of characters sent (or a negative value if there was an error).

Getting back to expression statements, an expression statement evaluates the expression, including side effects, and then discards the final value. So, in `a = 3;`, the side effect of storing 3 in `a` is performed, and the final value of 3 is ignored.

This is what happened with `+i;`. That is an expression statement with no side effects. It is fully defined C code. The expression is evaluated, and the result is discarded. `+` is a unary operator that simply provides the value of its operand. It is present in the language largely to provide symmetry with `-`, which negates its operand. So `+i;` is equivalent to `i;` which is equivalent to `;`, which does nothing.

Often a compiler will warn you about such statements because, although they are allowed and defined, they are useless. So the presence of such a statement in a program often indicates a mistake. If your compiler did not warn you about this, you should enable warnings. With GCC, you can start with `-Wall` but adjust the warnings further as you become familiar with them. With Clang, you can start with `-Wmost`. With Microsoft’s compiler, you can try `/W4`.

Once the compiler is warning you about expression statements that do nothing, you can explicitly tell the compiler that you deliberately want to ignore an expression by casting it to `void`, as in:

```
(void) +i;
```

There is no reason to do this in simple code, but sometimes circumstances arise in code involving conditional preprocessing or macros that leave fragments that are more easily ignored than eliminated.